# Updating a table's datetime field, adding seconds each time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have around 10,000 records where I would like to spread out the reserved processing DATETIME field, starting at a specific time.

So I would like to traverse all records, updating the date's seconds to a specific time, then the next record add 2 more seconds to the previous datetime, until all records has had 2 seconds added to a starting datetime.

i.e.
Row 1's Date1
2016-09-26 18:27:50.000
Row 2's Date2
2016-09-26 18:27:52.000
Row 3's Date3
2016-09-26 18:27:54.000

Can a while loop accomplish this?

```
create table #secondsiterate ( procdate datetime )
insert into #secondsiterate ( procdate )
select GETDATE()

WHILE (just want to add 2 seconds to each date field until it is done)
BEGIN
UPDATE #secondsiterate set procdate = DATEADD(ss,2,procdate)
END;
```

Comment: Perhaps something like `update T set procdate = dateadd(second, n*2, procdate) from (select *, row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 n from myTable) T`? I mean, you could do it with a while loop, but it seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to update "DateColumn" in table "MyTable", and there's a column "OrderColumn" (that is not DateColumn) in the table you can use to sort on to determine which rows get what values, then, the following SQL should do what you want.

```
DECLARE @startDate datetime;
SELECT @startDate = GETDATE(); -- Set this however you wish
UPDATE x
   SET DateColumn = DATEADD(SS, 2*rn, @startDate)
  FROM (SELECT *, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY orderColumn)) AS rn FROM YourTable) x
```

You need to set the @startDate variable ... either to current date (as shown) or maybe to MAX or MIN date of DateColumn from your table... however you need for your application.

The secret to avoiding WHILE and FOR loops is to use ROW_COUNT() in subselects or CTEs (Common Table Expressions). This lets you use set operations which are FAR faster and more efficient than iterative loops or cursors.